# Why Redirect to webpage not found?

Tags: php, session

I'm redirecting to page by link "welcome.php?language=english".

But when I place function 'confirm_patient_logged_in()' below Session declaration it's showing "Website not found". while it redirects to 'login.php' when this function is placed above Session declaration.

Can anyone tell what is reason behind this?

> Welcome.php

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/session.php"); ?>

<?php confirm_patient_logged_in(); ?>  //WORKING HERE

<?php

if(isset($_GET["language"])){
    if($_GET["language"] == "english"){
        $_SESSION["language"] = "english";
    }else{
        $_SESSION["language"] = "hindi";
    }
}

?>

<?php confirm_patient_logged_in(); ?>   // NOT WORKING HERE
```

Function:

```
function confirm_patient_logged_in(){
        if(!patient_logged_in()){
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }
}

function redirect_to($new_location){
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
    exit;
}
```

patient_logged_in() checks if user is logged-in or not

Comment: Please provide the details of the `redirect_to()` function and ping me.

Comment: I added an answer. Please take a look and tell me if it's not your case so I can update my answer.

Comment: session is already started in session.php

Comment: Please enable `display_error` on php.ini and tell me what error are you getting. Also please tell me what do you see in your browser's address bar in all variations, one by one. Lastly, please provide the details of **../../includes/session.php** file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to add `session_start();` before using `$_SESSION` variable:

```
<?php

require_once("../../includes/session.php");

session_start();

if(isset($_GET["language"])){
    if($_GET["language"] == "english"){
        $_SESSION["language"] = "english";
    }else{
        $_SESSION["language"] = "hindi";
    }
}

confirm_patient_logged_in();   // SHOULD WORK

?>
```

So it the missing `session_start();` was causing an error but you were unable to see the error probably `display_error` ini php.ini is disabled  and you were getting *Website not found* notification on your browser.